# Only return values that are positive in Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

So I am working on a project, a table that can show you which items you can make a profit of. The issue is that I want it to show the items that are above 1, aka all values that are positive. Right now it shows the products that you cant make a profit of as well!

Here is a picture of the website:
[image: picture]

Here is my python code:

```
@app.route('/bresell')
def reSell():
    farmingMerchantPrices = [
        5,  # cocoa beans
        12,  # brown mushroom
        2.33,  # carrot
        8,  # pumpkin
        2.33,  # wheat
        12,  # red mushroom
        2.33,  # potato
        4,  # sand
        5,  # sugar cane
        2,  # melon
    ]
    farmingMerchantName = [
        "Cocoa Beans",
        "Brown Mushroom",
        "Carrot",
        "Pumpkin",
        "Wheat",
        "Red Mushroom",
        "Potato",
        "Sand",
        "Sugar Cane",
        "Melon"
    ]
    sellPrice = []
    f = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=73ac0a44-4c41-4933-a9ee-b4095be2b6d2').json()
    for x in farmingProducts:
        sellPrice.append(f["products"][x]["sell_summary"][0]["pricePerUnit"])

    profit = []
    zip_object = zip(farmingMerchantPrices, sellPrice)
    for farmingMerchantPrices_i, sellPrice_i in zip_object:
        profit.append(sellPrice_i - farmingMerchantPrices_i)
```

My return statement is further down the code.

And here is my HTML:

```
<h1 class="npc-title">Farming Merchant</h1>
  <table
    id="myTable"
    class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm table-dark"
    cellspacing="0"
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th aria-label="Product Name" data-balloon-pos="up">Product</th>
        <th aria-label="How much you will earn" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Profit (x640)
        </th>
        <th aria-label="How much you will earn" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Profit (x1)
        </th>
        <th aria-label="NPC buy price" data-balloon-pos="up">
          NPC Buy Price
        </th>
        <th aria-label="Bazaar sell price" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Bazaar Sell Price
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for name, npcBuy, price, profit in zip(farmingMerchantName,
      farmingMerchantPrices,sellPrice, profit) %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ name }}</td>
        {% set profit2 = profit * 640%}
        <td>{{profit2|round(1, 'floor')}}</td>
        <td>{{ profit|round(1, 'floor') }}</td>
        <td>{{ npcBuy|round(1, 'floor') }}</td>
        <td>{{ price }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I am not sure how I can do it, I think I have to do an IF statement, to check if total profit is less than 1, but as you can see, I calculate the profit in my HTML!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja allows you to use if statements on html as well, so adding an if statement checking your profit on your html should do the trick:

```
<tbody>
  {% for name, npcBuy, price, profit in zip(farmingMerchantName,
  farmingMerchantPrices,sellPrice, profit) %}
  {% if profit > 1 %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ name }}</td>
    {% set profit2 = profit * 640%}
    <td>{{profit2|round(1, 'floor')}}</td>
    <td>{{ profit|round(1, 'floor') }}</td>
    <td>{{ npcBuy|round(1, 'floor') }}</td>
    <td>{{ price }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, you only checking for `profit`, then you can use `if` condition like below:

```html
{% for name, npcBuy, price, profit in zip(farmingMerchantName, farmingMerchantPrices,sellPrice, profit) %}
  {% if profit > 1 %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ name }}</td>
      {% set profit2 = profit * 640 %}
      <td>{{ profit2|round(1, 'floor') }}</td>
      <td>{{ profit|round(1, 'floor') }}</td>
      <td>{{ npcBuy|round(1, 'floor') }}</td>
      <td>{{ price }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```